# ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1): sorting issue Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am facing this sort issue:

> ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1):
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:156:in
>   `url_for'   actionview (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_view/routing_url_for.rb:94:in`url_for'   actionview
>   (4.2.6) lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:181:in `link_to'
>
>   app/helpers/application_helper.rb:7:in`sortable'
>   app/views/contacts/_sort.html.erb:3:in
>   `_app_views_contacts__sort_html_erb

This is my application_helper.rb:

```
  def sortable(column, title = nil)
    title ||= column.titleize.downcase
    css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
    direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
    link_to title, params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, :page => nil), {:class => css_class}
  end
```

In the above code, link_to is the line I am getting error in log.
This is my _sort.html.erb(rendered from index file):

```
<div id="sort_control"><a href="#">sort</a></div>
<ul class="sort" style="display:none;">
    <li><%= sortable "created_at" %></li> #here I am getting error
    <li><%= sortable "firstname" %></li>
  <li><%= sortable "lastname" %></li>
  <li><%= sortable "email" %></li>
</ul>
```

This is my controller method:

```
def index
    @contacts = Contact.search(params[:search]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => 60, :page => params[:page])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The error says you're passing 2 arguments into the `url_for` part of  your `link_to` method when it's expecting just 1.

Have you tried this?:

```
link_to title, {params.merge(sort: column, direction: direction, page: nil)}, class: css_class
```

Comment: It is raising error: `syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting =>
...rection: direction, page: nil)}, class: css_class
...              `

Comment: How are you getting `sort_direction` and `sort_column` in your `application_helper.rb` file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to Rails, but it looks like it doesn't like that your class is wrapped in {}

```
link_to title, params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, :page => nil), {:class => css_class}
```

According to the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to), it should look like this:

```
    link_to title, params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, :page => nil), class: css_class
```

An example shown:

> link_to "Articles", articles_path, id: "news", class: "article"